# Sign-In with google and playfab In Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-signin, playfab

Sign In with google through Playfab doesn't seem to work anymore after their (Google) Unity-plugin Update.

Playfab's Tutorial:
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/playfab/features/authentication/platform-specific-authentication/google-sign-in-unity).

The tutorials Playfab provided uses classes which doesn't exist anymore like
"PlayGamesClientConfiguration" Class.

The login With google function provided from Playfab plug-in needs ServerAuthCode as an arrgument, which used to be got from this function "PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.GetServerAuthCode()" which doesn't exist anymore.

So, do you have an idea how to do it given that their tutorials (Playfab login with google in Unity) is obselete now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the implementation and is working fine, but I used this package, not the latest one, is a previous version: https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/tree/v10/current-build

The Unity Package that appear in the Microsoft documentation have a lot of changes that create conflict with the tutorial.

For me is working for both platforms Android and iOS, if you have any problems, let me know.

Answer (score -1):

I met Playfab years ago, when I was looking for a multiplayer service that would allow me to provide as many features as possible to my game such as rankings, data cloud saves, authentication, etc.
After a while I chose to use PUN 2 together with Firebase instead.
[PUN 2](https://www.photonengine.com/pun) is a multiplayer service, which is now not the subject of the question.
I would recommend that you study [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com), because it has tons of very powerful services, many for free or at a fraction of the cost, and with much greater fame and support than Playfab from what I have seen.
In summary, clear Playfab for authentication and use [Firebase Auth](https://firebase.google.com/products/auth?gclid=CjwKCAjw2rmWBhB4EiwAiJ0mtTIn6TOWStT6lsfJJ2bi1GWsd-_xLF0nQFLyCtT2bOeudPzo1NzlGxoCVVoQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds). You can include sign in with Google, Apple, Microsoft, GitHub, email and password, anonymous etc.
Then it has an efficient password reset and email verification system.
I know if you have a project up and running it can be tedious to switch plugins, but Firebase has so many benefits that I think it's your best bet.

**if you think my answer helped you, you can mark it as [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). I would very much appreciate it :)**